# How to implement Privacy policy popup alert (Cookies Consent) in Meteor Js?

Tags: meteor

I am about implement Privacy policy alert in Meteor js framework. I am unsure about how to handle with Meteor cookies. Can someone guide me how do that in Meteor js Framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this implementation (with your individual adaptations for your likes): https://cookie-bar.eu/ in your main.html.

Otherwise you can have the popup created in your HTML and only show it with position fixed or absolute if the cookie is invalid/expired. Best location for this would be your app.js (your toppest level JS where you have your main content surrounded by header and footer.
For working with cookies you can use Ostrio's Meteor Cookies https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Cookies or the document.cookie API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: Thanks @Paul . Thats helpful.